# In Minecraft PE, is it possible to get on a server created for PC or can I only connect to PE servers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Using Minecraft PE, can I play on servers from PC like Mineverse or can I only play on Minecraft PE servers?

Comment: Ok sorry I didn't know if it was asked or not.

Answer (score 0):

No only your PC can use a PC server and your phone can only use a PE server.

Answer (score 0):

## No, you cant.

Minecraft PC servers can not be played on Minecraft Pocket Edition and vice versa. You can however, play Minecraft PE servers on PC using Minecraft Windows 10 edition.